# MySQL Events not deleting data after every 1 minute

Tags: mysql, database

Deletion is not taking place after every 1 minute.

```
delimiter $$
create event remove_notify
on schedule 
every 2 minute starts '2020-09-16' ends '2025-09-15'
do begin
    delete from email_verification 
    where timediff(now(),timestamp)> '00:02:00:00' ;
end $$;
delimiter ;
```

Table

```
Create table email_verification
(id int primary key,
timestamp datetime,
username varchar(255),
verify_code varchar(255));

INSERT INTO email_verification
values (1,'2020-09-15 23:57:20.567859','abc','12345');
```

Answer (score 0):

`'00:02:00:00'` is wrong time literal.

Use constants from one side of comparation operator and column from another side. I.e.

```
WHERE `timestamp` < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

PS. `timestamp` is reserved word, do not use it as column name (rename column), or at least quote it with backticks in your queries.